# Error with Jakarta in spring boot 3.1.0 the project does not compile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-migration

Greeting, someone can help me with an error in a spring boot application version 3.1.0 that use jakarta.
Before using a Jakarta dependency, the project compiled for me, but after adding the dependency
`implementation group: 'jakarta.platform', name: 'jakarta.jakartaee-api', version: '9.1.0'`

The project does not compile and I get this error

2023-10-18T00:19:11.408-05:00 ERROR 36064 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: UUID
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.co.loteriademedellin.lotterpmixturesvc.core.LotterpMixtureSvcApplication.main(LotterpMixtureSvcApplication.java:9) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UUID
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.registerJpaGenerators(StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.<init>(StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.<init>(StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactoryInitiator.initiateService(StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactoryInitiator.java:25) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactoryInitiator.initiateService(StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactoryInitiator.java:15) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:624) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

this is the build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        set("springBootVersion", '3.1.0')
        set("springCloudVersion", '2022.0.3')
        set("springDependencyManagementVersion", '1.1.0')
        set("jakarta-servlet.version", '5.0.0')
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${springDependencyManagementVersion}"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "${springDependencyManagementVersion}"
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'application'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

    java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }


    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
            exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        }
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
        implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
        implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
        implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
        implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j'
        implementation platform('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.12.494')
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core'
        implementation 'software.amazon.msk:aws-msk-iam-auth:1.1.7'
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
        runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8'
        annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.22'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '5.2.2'
        implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.1'
        implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
        implementation group: 'jakarta.platform', name: 'jakarta.jakartaee-api', version: '9.1.0'

    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        }
    }

    tasks.named('test') {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a service to generate an excel file

```
package com.co.loteriademedellin.lotterpmixturesvc.common.generator;


import com.co.loteriademedellin.lotterpmixturesvc.common.response.GenerateComponentExcelResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;
@Slf4j
public class ComponentExcelGenerator {

    private final List<List<GenerateComponentExcelResponse>> rows;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;
    private final String reportName;

    public ComponentExcelGenerator(List<List<GenerateComponentExcelResponse>> rows, OutputStream outputStream, String reportName) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.outputStream = outputStream;
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }

    private void createCell(SXSSFSheet sheet, Row row, int columnCount, Object value, CellStyle style){
        Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            cell.setCellValue((Integer) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            cell.setCellValue((Long) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            cell.setCellValue((Boolean) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            cell.setCellValue((Double) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Timestamp) {
            cell.setCellValue((Timestamp) value);
        } else {
            cell.setCellValue((String) value);
        }
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }

    private void writeHeaderLine(SXSSFWorkbook workbook, SXSSFSheet sheet){
        Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
        Row tittleRow = sheet.createRow(0);

        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        CellStyle tittleStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 16);
        font.setBold(true);

        Font tittleFont = workbook.createFont();
        tittleFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 16);
        tittleFont.setBold(true);


        style.setFont(font);
        tittleStyle.setFont(tittleFont);

        sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, 21));
        tittleStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 22));

        createCell(sheet, tittleRow, 0, reportName, tittleStyle);
        createCell(sheet, row, 0, "Código de la empresa", style);
        createCell(sheet, row, 1, "Código del producto", style);
        createCell(sheet, row, 2, "Código del billete", style);
        createCell(sheet, row, 3, "Código de la sucursal", style);
        createCell(sheet, row, 4, "Número", style);
        createCell(sheet, row, 5, "Serie de linea", style);
        createCell(sheet, row, 5, "Orden", style);

    }

    private void writeDataLines(SXSSFWorkbook workbook, SXSSFSheet sheet, List<GenerateComponentExcelResponse> colList){
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();

        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);

        style.setFont(font);
        int rowNum = 2;
        for (GenerateComponentExcelResponse response : colList){
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
            createCell(sheet, row, 0, response.getCompanyCode(), style);
            createCell(sheet, row, 1, response.getProductCode(), style);
            createCell(sheet, row, 2, response.getTicketCode(), style);
            createCell(sheet, row, 3, response.getBranchOfficeCode(), style);
            createCell(sheet, row, 4, response.getNumber(), style);
            createCell(sheet, row, 5, response.getLineSeries(), style);
            createCell(sheet, row, 6, response.getOrder(), style);
        }
    }

    public void export(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        try (SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(15)) {
            workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);

            for (List<GenerateComponentExcelResponse> cols : rows) {
                SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
                writeHeaderLine(workbook, sheet);
                writeDataLines(workbook, sheet, cols);
            }
            try {

                workbook.write(outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                workbook.dispose();
            } finally {
                workbook.dispose();
            }
            workbook.dispose();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.info("Error writing excel:  ", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: That dependency isn't needed, the needed api jars come already automatically. Remove the dependency. Next to that you have incompatible Apache POI versions, you are mixing 5.2.2 and 4.1.1. Just include the most recent version of `poi-ooxml` the rest will follow automatically.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem was the apache poi dependencies. you saved me !

Comment: Nonetheless you shouldn't be ading the Jakarta API as that shouldn't be needed in the first place, if anything it will only lead to issues when upgrading to later versions of Spring Boot.